# Tastypie: queryset = Model.objects.all()

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am newbie to Tastypie. I see that tastypie call Django Models using queryset and displays data.

My question is: if Tastypie builds the statement `queryset = < DJANGO-MODEL >.objects.all()`,
will it put a tremendous load on the database/backend if there are 100 million objects?

```
class RestaurentsResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Restaurents.objects.all()
        print queryset
        resource_name = 'restaurents'
```

Answer (score 2):

Django querysets are lazy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy, so no database activity will be carried out until the queryset is evaluated.

If you return all 1000 objects from your REST interface, then a 'tremendous' load will be placed on your server, usually pagination: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/paginator.html or similar is used to prevent this.

Calling `print` on the `queryset` as in the example class above, will force evaluation. Doing this in production code is a bad idea, although it can be handy when debugging or as a learning tool.

Comment: so you mean to say: if my url/uri is:api/v1/restaurents/8000/?format=json , tastypie will not fetch all objects and then filter object with pk/id = 3. It will prepare entire query and then fetch statement

Comment: if the query asks for object with pk/id = 3 then a single sql statement will be executed which returns one row from the table that represents the `Restaurant` object. It is possible to view all sql commands in the console when running `manage.py runserver`, if your curious.

Comment: Bt when I am printing value of queryset (print queryset) I see all objects being returned irrespective of URI (pk/id=3 or 1000 or all)

Comment: why are you calling print there? This will force evaluation of the `queryset` which is a bad idea

Comment: thats mr florence to you, ;)

Answer (score 1):

The two other answers are correct in terms of QuerySets being lazy.  But on top of that, the queryset you specify in the Meta class is the base for the query.  In Django, a QuerySet is essentially the representation of a database query, but is not executed.  QuerySets can be additionally filtered before a query is executed.

So you could have code that looks like:

```
Restaurant.objects.all().filter(attribute1=something).filter(attribute2=somethindelse
```

Tastypie just uses the QuerySet you provide as the base.  On each API access, it adds additional filters to the base before executing the new query.  Tastypie also handles some pagination, so you can get paginated results so not every row is returned.

While using all() is very normal, this feature is most useful if you want to limit your Tastypie results.  Ie, if your Restaurant resource has a 'hidden' field, you might set:

```
class Meta:
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.filter(hidden=False)
```

All queries generated by the API will use the given queryset as the base, and won't show any rows where 'hidden=True'.

Answer (score 0):

Django `QuerySet` objects are evaluated lazily, that is - the result is fetched from the db when it is really needed. In this case, `queryset = Restaurents.objects.all()` create a `QuerySet` that has not yet been evaluated.

The default implementation of `ModelResource` usually forces the queryset to be evaluated at dehydration time or paging. The first one requires model objects to be passed, the other one slices the queryset.

Custom views, authorization, or filtering methods can force the evaluation earlier.

That said, after doing all the filtering and paging, the results' list fetched is considerably smaller that the overall amount of data in the database.

Comment: If I change the the above api.py file as:


class RestaurentsResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
queryset = Restaurents.objects.all()
print queryset
resource_name = 'restaurents'

and GET query: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/restaurents/3/?format=json

I see in the command console:
[<Restaurents: Calypso>, <Restaurents: karans restaurant>, <Restaurents: uppi da
 dhaba>, <Restaurents: shiv sagar>, <Restaurents: Kshirsagar>]
[24/Nov/2013 03:27:32] "GET /api/v1/restaurents/3/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 224

Comment: @user3025983, that's because printing the queryset forces evaluation.

Comment: What if I want to filter/search the the queryset, then too the Objects  will forcefully evaluate?

Comment: Django builds the final sql statement out of the filters that are applied to the `queryset`, it is possible to chain multiple `.filter` and `.exclude` calls on a `queryset`. These will not be executed, until the `queryset` is iterated across, `print` or `list()` is called, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/